# Symmetric Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures

Checking whether a 2D Matrix is symmetric or not
Task is to output YES if the matrix is symmetric else output NO.

I am not getting the expected result. Can someone please help me out and please let me know what's wrong with this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool rev(int n)
{
int n1,d,rn=0;
n1=n;
while(n>0)
{
        d=n%10;
    rn=(rn*10)+d;
    n/=10;
}
if(n1==rn)
{return true;}
else
return false;
 }
 bool XAxisSymCheck(vector<int> vect)
 {
      // Declaring iterator to a vector 
    vector<int>::iterator ptr; 
    for (ptr = vect.begin(); ptr < vect.end(); ptr++) 
     { if(!rev(*ptr)) // reversing the elements in each element of vector to check whether its symmetric or not .. similar to palindrome
         {
            return false;
         }
     }
  }
  int main()
  {int testcase;
  cin>>testcase;
  for(int k=0;k<testcase;++k)
  {vector<int> rows;
  bool IsSymmetric=true;
  int row;
    cin >> row;
    // read each row and append to the "rows" vector
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        int line;
        cin >> line;
        rows.push_back(line);
    }
   if(XAxisSymCheck(rows))
   {int i,j;
   i=0;
   j=row-1;
   while(i<j) // looping through the elements of vector and checking the first element with last element , second element with the second last element and so on.
    {
     if(rows[i]!=rows[j])
       {
         IsSymmetric=false;
         break;
       }
     i++;
     j--;
    }
   }
   else
    {
     IsSymmetric=false;
    }   
    cout << (IsSymmetric ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
 }  
return 0;
}
```

Input:
First line contains T - number of test cases.
T test cases follow.
First line of each test case contains the N - size of matrix.
Next N lines contains binary strings of length N.

Output:
Print YES or NO in a new line for each test case

```
SAMPLE INPUT 
5
2
11
11
4
0101
0110
0110
0101
4
1001
0000
0000
1001
5
01110
01010
10001
01010
01110
5
00100
01010
10001
01010
01110

SAMPLE OUTPUT 
YES
NO
YES
YES
NO

Test Case #1: Symmetric about both axes, so YES.

Test Case #2: Symmetric about X-axis but not symmetric about Y-axis, so NO.

Test Case #3: Symmetric about both axes, so YES.

Test Case #4 and #5 are explained in statement.
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I am not getting the expected result. Can someone please help me out and please let me know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: So, which test case returns a wrong result?

Comment: For all the test cases its printing YES I am not sure why? Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with your code

1) You are never returning `true` from `XAxisSymCheck`  (this can easily discovered by inspecting the compiler warnings, eg `g++ -Wall matrix.cpp`)

```
bool XAxisSymCheck(vector<int> vect) {
    vector<int>::iterator ptr; 
    for (ptr = vect.begin(); ptr < vect.end(); ptr++) { 
        if(!rev(*ptr, vect.size()))
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

2) When your `XAxisSymCheck` fails, you are not setting `IsSymmetric` to `false` (at least in the original post before the edit)

```
for(int k=0;k<testcase;++k) {
    vector<int> rows;
    bool IsSymmetric = true;

    // ....

    if (XAsxisSymCheck(rows)) {
       // ...
    } else {
        IsSymmetric = false;
    }

    cout << (IsSymmetric ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
}
```

3) Your reverse check fails, if a line has leading zeros, because the reverse is not multiplicated by 10 often enough.

```
bool rev(int n,int len) {
    int n1,d,rn=0;
    n1=n;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        d=n%10;
        rn=(rn*10)+d;
        n/=10;
    }
    return n1==rn;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much.. I made the following changes and all the test cases have passed except the fourth test case.